# how to read beyond 0x20 in string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, space, smartcard-reader

I am trying to read data stored in a smart Card through a reader (ACS Reader), The driver came with a few DLLs which I imported into my C# .NET application (giving read write functions)

The problem I am facing now is the read functions, (int readValue(ref data (of string data type), int sector #, key etc.)), and the data I am trying to read now has SPACE (0x20) in it, say #### ## ## etc.

The output I am getting when reading is only till the first space #### and not the full block.

Is there way I can avoid this problem? say can I force the string type to understand spaces.

I was using an earlier application written in VS C++ 6 before and now I am trying to migrate to C#.

Comment: Can you post some code sample how u r reading the text? , Is it stream or string ?

Comment: Trying to debug your code when you haven't shown us any of it is quite tricky. There's no specific limitation in the framework about having strings containing space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [A Smart Card Framework for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET)